# Fail to use spark-excel to export a dataframe, due to dependency issue

Tags: excel, scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, sbt

I want to use the spark-excel library to export a dataframe to an Excel file. I can run the Spark job specifying which dependency to use with a parameter, but I would like it to work only using the sbt file to package the app (I understand that it's supposed to be pretty much the same thing).

In the build.sbt, this line specifies the dependency, along with some others that were already present :

```
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" % "spark-excel_2.11" % "0.12.0"
```

This is mainly based on this page : [Spark Excel Library](https://index.scala-lang.org/crealytics/spark-excel/spark-excel/0.8.4?target=_2.11)

Here is the command used to run it:

```bash
spark-submit --master spark://spark:7077 --class metro_export target/scala-2.11/metrologie_2.11-0.1.jar
```

When using this method, it doesn't work.

Here is how I run it with --package. I made sure these are the same version in both cases (I'm using Scala 2.11).

```
spark-submit --master spark://spark:7077 --packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.12.0 --class metro_export target/scala-2.11/metrologie_2.11-0.1.jar
```

In the scala code, there is the line which is supposed to export the dataframe (df) to the Excel file:

```
stats.write.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("useHeader", "true")
    .option("addColorColumns", "true")
    .save("stats.xlsx")
```

I works when submitting with `--packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.12.0`, but not without, even when I have the dependency in the sbt when packaging the jar (with `sbt package`).

Instead there is the error I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.crealytics.spark.excel. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
> at metro_export$.main(metro_export.scala:30)
> at metro_export.main(metro_export.scala)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
> at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
> at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
> ... 14 more

So why doesn't it find com.crealytics.spark.excel? Isn't that sufficient that the dependency is specified in the sbt?

Comment: hi did you find the answer for this?

Comment: @vigneshasokan Unfortunatly no, and I'm not working on this project anymore, so I won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still around there, the issue came from the import in his build.sbt. If you want to use it with the current latest version at the time of this post, if would be :

```
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel_2" % "0.13.1"
```

The author should have used

```
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" % "spark-excel_2" % "0.12.0"
```

instead of

```
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" % "spark-excel_2.11" % "0.12.0"
```